# Why does importing react-router-dom cause an error? Module not found: Can't resolve 'react'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

why does `import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";`
cause an error : `Module not found: Can't resolve 'react'`
everything worked normally until I imported react-router
this is full code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
...
import { Container } from 'reactstrap';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
...
class App extends Component {
 ...
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div className='App'>
          <AppNavbar />
          <Container>
            <ItemModal />
            <ShoppingList />
          </Container>
        </div>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using these in your component? can you show the code?

Comment: no, im not, just after importing

Comment: You are leaving out code. The error tells me that you are trying to `import react` but there is no react module installed. Hint: try `npm install react`

Comment: it is installed! it works again when i comment out the import router stuff

Comment: Post full code. That one line tells us nothing.

Comment: Can you verify that `node_modules/react` exists?

Comment: i can, the code works when i delete the import router part

Comment: in the error message the path for react node module changes and it falls one folder up so it should be `project/client/node_modules` and instead it is looking for react in `project/node_modules`

Comment: Oh, i installed router in wrong folder ... now it works.

Comment: @FilipFrank How did you do that if you used npm install>

Comment: because in upper folder i have my node.js server and i didnt do cd client to install router..